# Rounding up a double to the nearest integer

Tags: powershell, rounding

How can I convert a double to an int but make sure it rounds up regardless of the decimal value (as long as decimal value is not 0)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the .NET [`[Math]::Ceiling`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function and cast the result to `[int]`:

```powershell
PS > [int][Math]::Ceiling(1.1)
2   
PS > [int][Math]::Ceiling(1.6)
2
PS >
```

Comment: But why does this equal 101?: [int][Math]::Ceiling((100 / 11) * 11)

Comment: @Pete it'd have to do with the limit of computer storage. 100/11 = 9.0909.... forever, which is impossible to store in a computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$value = 7.1 
$floor = [math]::floor([int32]$value)
$ceiling = $result = [math]::ceiling([int32]$value)

$floor 
$ceiling
```

returns:

3

4